Deserialization Error in Kafka JMS Consumer: "Unknown magic byte 123"
I'm working on a Java application that consumes messages from a Kafka topic using a JMS listener within a Spring framework. The application is supposed to process user events from the USER_EVENT topic. Here is how my UserEventListener is implemented:
@Named
@Singleton
@Immutable
@ThreadSafe
public class UserEventListener extends MessageTypeInstrumentedMessageListener {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserEventListener.class);

    private final Map<KafkaEventWrapper.KafkaEventType, UserEventHandler<?>> userEventHandlersMap;

    @Inject
    public UserEventListener(List<UserEventHandler<?>> userEventHandlers) {
        this.userEventHandlersMap = userEventHandlers == null || userEventHandlers.isEmpty()
            ? new HashMap<>()
            : userEventHandlers.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(UserEventHandler::getHandleEventType, handler -> handler));
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageInternal(Message message) throws Exception {
        String messageStr = ((TextMessage) message).getText();

        try {
            final KafkaEventWrapper event = decode(messageStr);

            if (!userEventHandlersMap.containsKey(event.getType())) {
                LOG.warn("No handler for event type: {}", event.getType());
                return;
            }

            UserEventHandler<?> handler = userEventHandlersMap.get(event.getType());
            handler.handle(event);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Unable to process user event: {}", messageStr, e);
        }
    }

    private KafkaEventWrapper decode(final String message) {
        return JsonTransformer.UGLY.fromJson(message, KafkaEventWrapper.class);
    }
}

The worker-context.xml configuration for the listener is as follows:
<bean id="kafkaListenerContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="destinationName" value="USER_EVENT" />
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1" />
    <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="1" />
    <property name="messageListener" ref="userEventListener" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="instrumentedKafkaFactory" />
    <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true" />
    <property name="maxMessagesPerTask" value="1" />
</bean>

The Kafka consumer properties are set in this way:
<util:map id="kafkaSettings" map-class="java.util.HashMap">
    <entry key="bootstrap.servers" value="${confluent.bootstrapServer}" />
    <entry key="security.protocol" value="SASL_SSL" />
    <entry key="sasl.jaas.config" value="org.apache.kafka.common.security.plain.PlainLoginModule required username='${confluent.apiKey}' password='${confluent.apiSecret}';" />
    <entry key="sasl.mechanism" value="PLAIN" />
    <entry key="acks" value="all" />
    <entry key="enable.auto.commit" value="true" />
    <entry key="auto.commit.interval.ms" value="100" />
    <entry key="key.serializer" value="org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer" />
    <entry key="key.deserializer" value="org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer" />
    <entry key="value.serializer" value="org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer" />
    <entry key="value.deserializer" value="org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer" />
    <entry key="consumer.group.id" value="worker-user-kafka-consumer" />
</util:map>

Despite this setup, I'm encountering the following errors in the logs, and onMessageInternal is never reached:
ERROR io.confluent.serializers.ProtoSerde - Tried to deserialize message with unknown magic byte 123
ERROR org.apache.kafka.connect.util.KafkaBasedLog - Error polling: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition USER_EVENT-0 at offset 5. If needed, please seek past the record to continue consumption.

My main problem is this message (which likely is a test message that was published manually at some point), poison-pills me and I can not at least acknowledge the message. I can't find a way to catch a deserialization exception.
What I've Tried:

Configured the consumer to use StringDeserializer for both key and value.
Added an ExceptionListener to catch exceptions during message reception:

@Named
public class UserEventExceptionListener implements ExceptionListener {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserEventExceptionListener.class);

    @Override
    public void onException(JMSException exception) {
        LOG.error("JMS Exception occurred. Continuing processing...", exception);
    }
}

And updated the configuration:
<property name="exceptionListener" ref="userEventExceptionListener" />


Implemented a custom SafeStringDeserializer:

public class SafeStringDeserializer implements Deserializer<String> {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SafeStringDeserializer.class);

    @Override
    public String deserialize(String topic, byte[] data) {
        try {
            return data == null ? null : new String(data, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("Failed to deserialize message from topic {}: {}", topic, e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
}

Updated the consumer properties:
<entry key="value.deserializer" value="com.example.SafeStringDeserializer" />

Despite these efforts, the problem persists.

Why am I still getting deserialization errors with magic byte 123 even after configuring the deserializers to handle JSON?
How can I correctly configure my JMS Kafka consumer to process messages formatted as JSON without deserialization errors?
Is there a way to bypass or handle these poison pill messages so that the consumer can continue processing other messages?


Please share full stacktrace. Nowhere in the question are you using Protobuf , so why does the error say ProtoSerde?
